# How to use sql statement in django?

Tags: sql, django

I want to get the latest date from my database.
Here is my sql statement.

```
select "RegDate"
from "Dev"
where "RegDate" = (
 select max("RegDate") from "Dev")
```

It works in my database.
But how can I use it in django?

I tried these codes but it return error. These code are in views.py.

Version 1:

```
lastest_date = Dev.objects.filter(reg_date=max(reg_date))
```

Error:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Version 2:

```
last_activation_date = Dev.objects.filter(regdate='reg_date').order_by('-regdate')[0]
```

Error:

```
"'reg_date' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."
```

I've defined reg_date at beginning of the class.

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make things too complicated, you simply order by `regdate`, that's all:

```
last_activation_dev = Dev.objects.order_by('-regdate').first()
```

The `.first()` will return such `Dev` object if it is available, or `None` if there are no `Dev` objects.

If you only are interested in the `regdate` column itself, you can use `.values_list(..)`:

```
last_activation_date = Dev.objects.order_by('-regdate').values_list('regdate', flat=True).first()
```

By using `.filter()` you actually were *filtering* the `Dev` table by `Dev` records such that the `regdate` column had as *value* `'reg_date'`, since `'reg_date'` is not a valid datetime format, this thus produced an error.